# Detect keypress globally in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I want to detect key press on whole website that is to listen keypress globally. I tried adding onKeyDown property on div in react but it doesn't catch global event

```html
<div onKeyPress={(e) => console.log(e)}>
    <MainLayout visualizerMode={true} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by listening to `onKeyDown` type event, in document object.

Add this to your react component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(e))
}, [])
```

Hope, it's helpful!